# Images in the github repository dont upload to github pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I just finished a project's mobile version and uploaded it on Github. Then I open a Github page to the project. Even though all my image files uploaded on the repository, in the Github page, not all the image files are uploading.

It's not a source problem. Images are doesn't show in the source. They are not uploaded on the page.

Github repository: https://github.com/atilganf/cafeSite

Github page: https://atilganf.github.io/cafeSite/

Comment: The images are there. The URLs to the images in your HTML are wrong. Replace `../img` by `img`

Comment: Ty, it fixed. I thought it was a different problem because it wasn't shown in the source.

Comment: But can I ask another question? Is there a way to upload the slider's images with the page other than with sliders code. Because they upload each time the slider changes with the sliders code and it doesn't look good. @JBNizet

Comment: I don't understand you question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. This is what I see when looking at the "Network" tab from Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

Notice that this URL is working just fine: https://atilganf.github.io/cafeSite/img/banner1.jpg

The URLs of images have https://atilganf.github.io/cafeSite/ as their base. Hence, changing the links from:

```
../img/banner1.jpg
```

to:

```
img/banner1.jpg
```

should help.

Places in code where `../img -> img` change should occur:

- https://github.com/atilganf/cafeSite/blob/master/css/main.css#L149
- https://github.com/atilganf/cafeSite/blob/master/js/main.js#L34
- https://github.com/atilganf/cafeSite/blob/master/css/main.css#L149
- https://github.com/atilganf/cafeSite/blob/master/css/main.css#L188